# Toggling not working properly - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code which sould toggle between elements, if user opens the element all other elements should close and that works, but if I click on the same element multiple times nothing happens and I cant figure out why. I need some help.

Here is my code:

```
const heads = [...document.querySelectorAll(".head")];
const dropdowns = [...document.querySelectorAll(".head-dropdown")];
const activate_filter = document.getElementById("filter-btn");

let isActive = false;
let isFilterActive = false;
let queue = [];

if (!isFilterActive) {
  dropdowns.forEach((val, i) => {
    val
      .querySelector(".dropdown-search")
      .setAttribute(
        "name",
        `${heads[i].querySelector("p").textContent}-search`
      );
  });
}

activate_filter.addEventListener("click", e => {
  dropdowns.forEach((val, i) => {
    val.classList.remove("activated");
    val.dataset.isActivated = false;
  });
  if (!isFilterActive) {
    heads.forEach((val, i) => {
      const p = val.children[0];
      p.innerHTML += `<i class='eos-icons'>arrow_drop_down</i>`;
      val.addEventListener("click", handleEventAll);
      val.style.cursor = "pointer";
    });
    isFilterActive = true;
  } else {
    heads.forEach(val => {
      const p = val.children[0];
      const i = p.querySelector("i");
      if (i) {
        i.remove();
      }

      val.removeEventListener("click", handleEventAll);
      val.style.cursor = "default";
    });
    isFilterActive = false;
  }
});

function handleEventAll(e) {
  const test = e.target.querySelector(".head-dropdown");
  test.classList.add("activated");
  queue.unshift(test);
  if (queue.length > 3) {
    queue.pop();
  }

  dropdowns.forEach((val, i) => {
    if (!val.dataset) {
      val.dataset.isActivated = false;
    }
    let t = eval(queue[0].dataset.isActivated);
    console.log(t);
    if (t) {
      console.log("in true", queue[0]);
      queue[0].dataset.isActivated = true;
      queue[0].classList.toggle("activated");
      queue.pop();
    } else {
      console.log("in false", queue[0].dataset);
      queue[0].dataset.isActivated = false;
      console.log(queue);
      queue[1].classList.remove("activated");

      queue.pop();
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("click", e => {});
```

The elements are added to the queue and the queue sorts it out if previous element which was opened is properly closed and it opens a new element which is clicked. If the same element is clicked twice the queue closes the element but does not open it again until some other element is clicked.

Here is codepen for full experience: https://codepen.io/darioKolic/pen/eYdYzdy

Comment: You are adding the activated class and then removing it again, both adding and deleting is performed in the same event.

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: I rewrote the handleEventAll function to make the required functionality without using a queue. check this https://codepen.io/WaleedJubeh/pen/rNMNMxR

Comment: If this what you want, I can post it as answer

Comment: Thats it, thank you. you can post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the handleEventAll function to make the required functionality without using a queue. [check this](http://ww.codepen.io/WaleedJubeh/pen/rNMNMxR)

What I did is save the current state (is activated class exist or not) for clicked element, and then I remove all activated class from all element then add or remove the class activated depends on the old value.